# Extract data from 1 column in txt with Power Query

Tags: powerquery, text-extraction, txt, custom-code

I have some files from SAP system. They are exported in .txt. They have the same structure. The idea is to arrange the data into a more user friendly way using Power Query, especially since there are many such files weekly, and we are unable to report based on txt file.

After I have done some cleaning, the data looks like this:
[PQ image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHcni.png)

And have no clue how to continue, to extract the data into a different colum, like Vendor Number, Vendor Name, Document, Amount etc..

Comment: did you remove items in your sample, replacing them with spaces?

Comment: @horseyride - no, did not replace anything with spaces. Would this help in any way? I am still a newbie with Power Query, so learning as I go.

Comment: pleaser provide (a) a text version of the sample input (b) sample output based on the input

Comment: Here is the example file in txt - i have put it on wetransfer https://wetransfer.com/downloads/06a35a1cb50212fa62e019b53d19aa3020220525174709/9804b735710d2212e2f726115c1f7a9f20220525174735/3c2252